# Copy a ckeditor instance value to another field

Tags: 9

In a form I have a ckeditor field and I would need to copy its value to another field using a jquery blur event.
Do you guys know how I could do that?
I was thinking about a ckeditor plugin but I don't think I will be able to interact with another field from that plugin.

Comment: This is way easier in CKEditor 5, so you might try updating to the experimental CKEditor 5 module since it will roll out with Drupal 10 anyway.

Comment: I would try adding an AJAX callback to the body field via form_alter. I've never tried on a body/CKE field so IDK if it will work, so hopefully.